# Texts in NumberPicker are cut off

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have dialog with NumberPicker security questions. The long texts are cut off. How to solve this issue?

[image]

This is layout's content for dialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
<com.aperto.ext.edekaapp.ui.CustomFontButton
    android:id="@+id/reg_fields_number_dialog_button"
    style="@style/BlueButton.Big"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/reg_fields_number_dialog_button_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can put `new Line` command on String like: `"Hello\n world"`, using `\n` in the middle

Comment: Is it a singleLine text field?

Comment: You should use `"Hello\nworld"` else you will see a space first in the new line.

Comment: @Aspicas Number picker removes(ignores) new lines (\n)

Comment: That it's because your text field it's a singleLine, try to change it, do you have a XML right? can you post it? @hhs

Comment: @Aspicas this is en NumberPicker view, i don't have any TextView

Comment: @hhs yes, but sure, you have a `XML` file with that design, or... you should have it... haha

Comment: @hhs i can't find a good solution, i'm so sorry, maybe another users can help you...

Comment: @Aspicas thank you :)

Comment: Got the same problem. Tried to set this view multiline but that works even if the view is focused. What a fail concept...

Comment: hi! have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I managed to fix it by giving the `NumberPicker` a large `layout_margin`.

After adding this line:

```
android:layout_margin="60dp"
```

my number picker no longer truncates the text and it appears to have no layout issues.